# Unable to expect multiple exceptions with JUnit's ExpectedException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

- Java 7
- JUnit 4.11

I'm writing tests to validate my methods' contracts, e.g., a parameter cannot be `null`, an `int` param must be positive, etc. When a contract is violated, the thrown exception type reflects why it failed, such as `NullPointerException` or `IllegalArgumentException`. Sometimes I don't care which of these two is thrown, only that *one of them* is thrown. (Yes, I *should* be testing for the exact exception type, but bear with me...)

I could use JUnit's `@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)` (since `RuntimeException` is the closest common parent of `IAE` and `NPE`), but this is overly generic as the method under test might throw some other `RuntimeException`.

Instead, I'm trying to use JUnit's [`ExpectedExceptions`](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) class.

Here is a complete example:

```
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.anyOf;

public class ParameterViolationTest {
    private Target target = new Target();

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expected = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void parameterViolation() {
        expected.expect(anyOf(
                CoreMatchers.<Class<? extends Exception>>
                        equalTo(NullPointerException.class),
                CoreMatchers.<Class<? extends Exception>>
                        equalTo(IllegalArgumentException.class)));

        // Null parameter violates contract, throws some exception.
        target.methodUnderTest(null);
    }

    private static class Target {
        public void methodUnderTest(Object o) {
            if (o == null) {
                // throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect this test to pass, but instead it fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (<class java.lang.NullPointerException> or <class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException>)
     but: was <java.lang.NullPointerException>
Stacktrace was: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ParameterViolationTest$Target.methodUnderTest(ParameterViolationTest.java:35)
    at ParameterViolationTest.parameterViolation(ParameterViolationTest.java:25)
    < internal calls... >
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:168)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    < internal calls... >
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (<class java.lang.NullPointerException> or <class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException>)
     but: was <java.lang.NullPointerException>
Stacktrace was: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ParameterViolationTest$Target.methodUnderTest(ParameterViolationTest.java:35)
    at ParameterViolationTest.parameterViolation(ParameterViolationTest.java:25)
    < internal calls... >
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:168)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    < internal calls... >
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:865)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:832)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.handleException(ExpectedException.java:198)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$500(ExpectedException.java:85)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:177)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    < internal calls... >
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `Matchers.instanceOf` instead of `CoreMatchers.equalTo`, because you're comparing instances of `XXXException`.

```
expected.expect(anyOf(
  instanceOf(NullPointerException.class),
  instanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class)));
```

Comment: Ah ha, you are right, and it's much easier to read. I see now that JUnit was comparing the instance of the thrown exception to the exception _class_ I told it to expect. (`NullPointerException != class NullPointerException`). That's why it failed. Thank you.

Comment: How do you combine this with different messages for each exception? I expect `UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet")` (and no other message) and `IllegalArgumentException` (any message).

Comment: `anyOf(allOf(...), instanceOf(...))`